# Power-Consumption, switching off Graphiccard?

Tags: nvidia, power-management

I'm pretty new to Linux, nevertheless I built a server from an old computer and I'm currently running ownCloud, Minecraft and a Webpage on it. I would like to reduce the power consumption to a minimum.

First of all:

**Monitoring:** I tried to get PowerTop to show me actual Wattage Comsumption to define who is the most demanding part there.
unfortunately `powertop --calibrate` does not give me that information.

So I'm guessing that the Graphics card (Geforce 210) is using pretty much a lot of the power. Powertop also says, that the 210 is "used" for 100%. I'm using the default nouveau-driver. And I'm starting ubuntu in text-mode (GRUB_TERMINAL=console  //text base grub menu)

The server is only used in SSH, no Monitor, nor a Keyboard attached.

**Specifications:**

- Q6600, slightly undervolted.
- Asus Geforce EN210
- Seagate 7200.12 HDD
- 1 Gigabit Ethernet card.

Total Power Comsumption @idle: 68 Watt

Any hints that i could follow to reduce more power consumption?
Any hints to have proper monitoring?
Can i switch off the Graphics card at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see on google Geforce 210 is external graphic card. You dont need this in your server so just take it out of your server box.
Also change your bios settings, there must be something for Power Mangament.
There is pretty much nothing on the OS side that can reduce power consumption.
Good luck.

Comment: Oh wow, i was pretty sure you would have to have a Gra-card to even boot up-- i learned today. Thanks. It saves 9 Watts.